# Wpf - Contextmenu in TabItem Header

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, tabitem

I wanted to add a contextmenu to a tabitem. But it should only be opened by clicking on the header of the tab. 
I added the Contextmenu like this:

```
ContextMenu _contextMenu;
TabItem _tabItem;
//Initialize the components
_tabItem.ContextMenu = _contextMenu;
```

Only if you klick on the header of the TabItem, the ContextMenu should be opened.

[image: It should only work by right-klicking in the header]

But if you klick at another position of the tabItem, it shouldn´t be displayed.

[image: If you don´t klick on the header, it shouldn´t displayed]

I need to do that programmatically during the runtime. A solution in xaml is ok, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like:

```
_tabItem.Header = new ContentControl
                 {
                     Content = "StartPage",
                     ContextMenu = _contextMenu
                 };
```